My outfix did record infixes
My prefix is like $\cup$
My infix is like $\bigcirc$
My suffix is like $\supset$
I move like $\downarrow$
Line 1 hint:

 trek

Line 2 hint:

 track


Does the knowledge tag apply here?

@PDT, at first I had the knowledge tag, then replaced it with visual. It was for the title, but it's pretty well known.

It was full moon last night.  But I don't know what to do with that down arrow.

Just wondering, no need to know mathematical symbols?

@Prim3numbah, correct, this doesn't need knowledge of mathematical symbols.

Any chance for a hint ?

I've been having an idea, but can't make everything to make sense, is it somehow related to rot13(Gheagnoyr/erpbeq cynlre)?

@Prim3numbah, valid idea but off track - a different kind of rot13(erpbeq).

Does outfix mean all parts of the word that are not the infix?

@JLee, I considered an outfix as some initial letters followed by some final letters

I think you are cluing the word...

 COLLAPSE, and the symbols used in the riddle are intended to reflect the shapes of items being described here...

My prefix is like ∪

 COL - a word meaning the lowest point of a ridge between two peaks. The clue 'trek' in Hint 1 leads us to think of mountain walks...

My infix is like ◯

 LAP - a circuit of a running or racing 'track' (from Hint 2).

My suffix is like ⊃

 APSE - a recess in a church.

I move like ↓

 COL+LAP+APSE (with overlap) = COLLAPSE. When something undergoes a COLLAPSE, it tends to sag or slump downwards, as per this arrow!

As for the title, "My outfix did record infixes":

 The Olympic athlete Sebastian COE set 9 outdoor and 3 indoor world records in middle-distance track events, generally at distances of 800m and 1500m, which both involved running LAPs of a running track. 'COE' is an 'outfix' of COLLAPSE (the letters CO...E appear at its outer limits...).


Correct as usual - I like the profile pic!

@Tom Phew! Surprisingly tricky to bend the head around this one! (And thanks - I semi-regularly update it with a new depiction of me and my daughter as drawn by her. Anyone who's been following my profile pics over the years will be getting a virtual flickbook of her improving technique and my declining hairline!)

Is it a

 gramophone / turntable / record player
 

My prefix is like ∪

 The needle

My infix is like ◯

 The disc / record

My suffix is like ⊃

 The speaker

I move like ↓

 The needle moves along the track / disc / record this way

(I had this in mind before I saw Prim3numbah's comment, but it did reinforce my idea.)

affix-riddle:
An affix riddle is a specific type of riddle that clues the target word by describing multiple, possibly overlapping parts of the word separately. Usually the beginning (prefix), the middle (infix), and the end (suffix) of the word are described. Sometimes referred to as Riley riddles.


 You're an old-fashioned elevator! The button to call the elevator has a U (for "up") on top, a D (for "down") on the bottom, and a circle in the middle.


 A similar design: 


What about:  I move like $\downarrow$?

I highly doubt this is what the OP had in mind

@Will.Octagon.Gibson I didn't explain that one because I thought it was the most obvious. An elevator moves downward. (And also upward fwiw.)

interesting: does $\bigcirc$ $\downarrow$ $\cup$ $\supset$ spell OTIS in some way?

somewhat wild guess (visual)

 triggered by Florian F comment

you see

 moon in the morning in the east coming up $\cup$ shape

then

 at noon you start your journey moving away from the equator $\bigcirc$ when the sun $\bigcirc$ shines from right above you

note that

 on the equator moon (and sun) always turn an almost perfect (half) circle $\bigcirc$ since they all move in almost same plane

finally

 you end up south(pole) $\downarrow$ to see same moon $\supset$ shape in the evening

fwiw

 if you did not move south you would see same moon going down $\cap$ shape on the equator 12 hours later in the evening

and

 if you moved $\uparrow$ to the north(pole) instead you would see same moon going down $\subset$ shape

about fixes:

 pre- in- suf- fixes are in 12h daytime but out- fix I have no idea :)

